# accept() failing after successful socket(), bind(), listen() with errno 88 ENOTSOCK

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, signals

Trying to get my simple FTP server running. It is running on a remote server. Using `cat /etc/*-release` reveals the server is running CentOS Linux 7 core.

Referenced: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/, specifically:

> Specifies a socket that was created with socket(), has been bound to an address with bind(), and has issued a successful call to listen().

My program successfully calls `socket`, `bind`, and `listen` - then `accept` fails on the server. On OSX 10.11.5 it works just fine (after commenting out a few headers).

I am compiling remotely with `gcc -std=c11 ftserver.c -o ftserver`. Using logging and stderr I get the following from execution to it throwing exit(1).

Logging output (edit):

```
ftserver 30000   <-- start the server on port 30000
socket() succeeded with sockfd = 3
bind() succeeded with sockfd = 3
listen() succeeded with sockfd = 3
Server open on 30000
ERROR: Obtaining new socket descriptor with 
    sockfd = 0
    temp_sockfd = -1
    errno = 88
```

Here is the code from the programs entry point to the line that throws the error.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ftserver <port number>\n");
    exit(1);
}

int port = atoi(argv[1]);
char client_hostname[STRING_LENGTH];
bzero(client_hostname, STRING_LENGTH);

// set up the server's socket
int sockfd;
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[ ERROR ] :: main() :: Failure to assign sockfd");
    exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("socket() succeeded with sockfd = %d\n", sockfd);
}

// fill the client socket address struct
struct sockaddr_in addr_client;
addr_client.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr_client.sin_port = htons(port);
addr_client.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(addr_client.sin_zero), 8);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_client, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[ ERROR ] :: main() :: Failure to bind port %d. Please select another port\n", port);
    exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("bind() succeeded with sockfd = %d\n", sockfd);
}

if (listen(sockfd, QUEUE) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[ ERROR ] :: main() :: Failure to listen on port %d\n", port);
    exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("listen() succeeded with sockfd = %d\n", sockfd);
}

printf ("Server open on %d\n", port);

struct sigaction signal_action;
signal_action.sa_handler = kill_zombies;
sigemptyset(&signal_action.sa_mask);
signal_action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &signal_action, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("sigaction");
    return 1;
}
else {
    printf("sigaction succeeded\n");
}

struct sockaddr_in addr_server;
int temp_sockfd;

while (1) {
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // accept() is used to connection to a client
    if ((temp_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_server, &sin_size)) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Obtaining new socket descriptor with \n\tsockfd = %d\n\ttemp_sockfd = %d\n\terrno = %d\n", sockfd, temp_sockfd, errno);

        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("accept() succeeded\n");
    }
// more code that we never have the pleasure to exec
```

And the headers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>

// includes for server (CentOS) errors
// comment these out to compile locally (OSX)
// fixes error: ‘WNOHANG’ undeclared
#include <sys/wait.h>

// fixes error: ‘SA_RESTART’ undeclared
#include <asm/signal.h>
```

Comment: Errno 88 generally indicates a socket operation on non-socket. Pls print the sockfd values after each operation and also double check if you are not meddling with it elsewhere.

Comment: `if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_client, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 )` I think it should be `sizeof sockaddr_in` or `sizeof addr_client`

Comment: @Jay - I've updated my post in two place. One is the logging output with `sockfd` values as you suggested. The second is the code that makes the output (consistency eh?). The code above is the entry point to the program, nothing is called or executed before what I have posted.

Comment: So something is zeroing the socket FD. Try commenting out the sigaction stuff.

Comment: "*`sockfd = 0`*" what is this?

Comment: In `(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_client, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 )` I have tried replacing `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` with `sizeof(addr_client)` and with `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`. Both output the same logs as in the main post.

Comment: @EJP - that fixed it. Why `sigaction` is zeroing out sockfd is beyond me. Good tip, I never would have thought to try that.

Comment: Something wrong with that code. NB you have client and server sockaddr back to front.

Comment: `struct sigaction signal_action;` is not properly initialised. Do `struct sigaction signal_action = {0};` and retest.

Comment: @FearJoy I was not saying that it would fix the problem. Still you should pass the correct size.

Comment: The logging output is missing the "sigaction succeeded". Are your sure about your program flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs you show

> `sockfd = 0`

it is obvious that between the calls to `listen()` and `accept()` the FD `sockfd` gets overwritten (here: to `0`).

This most likely dues to undefined behaviour being invoked some where then or before.

The latter most likely dues to passing a ***not*** completely initialised `struct sigaction` to `sigaction()`.

To fix this, properly initialise the `struct sigaction` for example like this:

```
struct sigaction signal_action = {0};
```